# using p4.net in web services

Tags: c#, web-services, deployment, .net-3.5, perforce

I am using p4.net(perforce api for .net) to connect our perforce server and run some commands.

I have created a web service and and created a test call(ConnectToServer), when I test this web service on local(localhost:xxxx/project/test.asmx) it works perfectly, however, when I deploy my web service to out server and call the my "connect" web method,  it comes up and says Unable to connect Perforce Server.

what is the difference between local and server, they both use same dlls to connect perforce, and they are both web service, why do you guys think it throws an error on server? is that configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look deeper into how and where you actually set the Perforce connection parameters. As you say that the username property returns NETWORK_SERVICE, this indicates that that the Perforce user is not explicitly set, and falls back at attempting to use the current OS user.

Just to verify this: Try to set the relevant P4Connection properties such as User, Password and Port explicitly in the code *immediately* before connecting to the Perforce server. This should work unless you have any connectivity and/or protection issues between the web server and the Perforce server (which doesn't seem to be the case).

If the above works, and you believe that you were already doing this - is there a chance that you are setting up the properties for one P4Connection instance and using another for the actual connection attempt?

You also don't say how you attempt to set the credentials; do you attempt to use e.g. p4 set (which wouldn't work in this case) or environment variables (which would then need to set for the correct OS user or globally), or are you currently setting the P4Connection properties explicitly, or what?

**Update:**
The poster was attempting to use P4HOST (or equivalent) instead of P4PORT, see comments below. There are still some unexpected results in the various tests performed as a result of the other replies, but all are probably related to the root problem.

Comment: using (P4Connection instance = new P4Connection())
            {
                try
                {
                    instance.User = "test"; 
                    instance.Password = "pwd";
                    instance.Host = "testdomain.org:1666";
                    instance.Connect();
                    return "connected";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.Message;
                }
            }

Comment: the code above works perfectly in a windows application. but not on the web server. this is a very simple test, any idea?

Comment: @AnarchistGeek: Use instance.Port instead of instance.Host. Host tells you where the client is, not where the server is. It probably succeeds in the application because you have P4PORT set in the environment or by using p4 set.

Comment: @AnarchistGeek: If this fixed the problem ... well, I'll update my answer, and then it's up to you to select the best one.

Comment: @Cwan, it connects to p4 server. But it still does not work. the new error message is Error running Perforce command! Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset. I get this error message when I try to consume the service. it says password is invalid, whereas p4 client works ok. Ans web service works without any problem on local machine, do you have any idea why it is so? Cheers

Comment: @Cwan, sure., i thought, it might be related to this issue.

Comment: @AnarchistGeek: It's probably a variation of the same problem, I just thought that this question was starting to become a conversation. A new question with a more specific topic might be better. What you could try to do is to make sure that you explicitly set the same variables when using p4.exe as from the code, e.g. "p4 -u test -P pwd -p testdomain.org:1666 -c client <some command>"

Answer (score 1):

Which type of authentication / impersonation are you using in your web service web.config?

Which user does the service run under when on the remote server?

Does this user have sufficien access privileges for Perforce?

These would be my first questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave. I am using Windows authentication in my web.config. On IIS, Enable anonymous access is checked and IUSR_Servername is used as User. this user basically not on the perforce, does it have to be?

Comment: Yes, when the service runs, it will try to connect to Perforce as IUSR_Servername. I recommend creating a service account user for this service to talk to Perforce with, and then granting permissions to that user.

Comment: But I specify perforce user account and password explicitly, why it will try to connect perforce server as IUSR_Servername?

Comment: Dave; I instrumented the a bit and have seen that it is trying to use NETWORK_SERVICE user. To be honest, I did not understand why... do you have any idea?

Comment: It looks as if impersonation is switched off, so your web service will run as the IIS worker process account. This article shows a useful table containing which user your code runs under in different circumstances, depending on security settings in web.config: http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount
I think you need to create a service account, change IIS to use that account instead of NETWORK SERVICE, and grant access to that account in Perforce.

Comment: same error:( Unable to connect to the Perforce Server! Unable to connect to Perforce!|||| at P4API.P4Connection.EstablishConnection(Boolean tagged)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check there is no firewall issues on the server?
What is the exact error message from p4.net?

Comment: the firewall is off and the error is P4API.Exceptions.PerforceInitializationError: Unable to connect to the Perforce Server! Unable to connect to Perforce! thanks

Comment: Can you connect from the server with the command line client?

Comment: Yes I can, I also created a simple windows project and used p4.api, works fine. the issue is, the api uses network credentials for connecting to p4. because when I get the username property of the connection, it returns "NETWORK_SERVICE" instead of p4 user, even though I have specified the p4 user explicitly.